# How to send a JSON array by route value to the action method (MVC 4)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen more than 30 Q&As about sending json arrays, however I have a different and strange problem...

I have a view that it represent some data by jqgrid to the user. User manipulates some rows of it and call an action method to show a report based on that data. My problem is that I **MUST** send that array by route values and I can't get rid of the `Bad Request - Invalid URL` error...

Corresponding part of my view:

```
// ... some correct codes before
var bpics = [],           
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
        var pid = "#chk" + myData[i].ID,
            sid = "#ddl" + myData[i].ID,
            pic = {
                PersonnelName: myData[i].PersonnelName,
                FatherName: myData[i].FatherName,
                BirthDate: myData[i].BirthDate,
                Education: myData[i].Education,
                UniversityName: myData[i].UniversityName,
                PostName: $(pid).val(),
                Phone: myData[i].Phone,                    
                NeedSettle: $(sid).val()
            };
        bpics.push(pic);
    }        

    window.open("../RawPrint/GetBurseLetterReport/" + JSON.stringify(bpics)
        + "/" + $("#txtDestManName").val()
        + "/" + $("#ddlUniversity").val()
        + "/" + $("#lblCourseTitle").text());
// ... some other correct codes after ...
```

In fact I'm using `StimulSoft Reports` and this component dictates the developer to send variables by route values. So, I'm struggling to send that JSON string by route values (because I must...!).

Some works that I've done:

in web config, I added the following tags. However the just work when I use `$.ajax` to send the json array...:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""   requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

and

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

Any help, tip, trick, ... ?!

Comment: Change your window.open to first put the url into a variable, then copy and paste the value into your browser. Does it look correctly formed?

Comment: I think that the url gets too long... more that 700 chars...! is it the problem?!

Comment: Are you receiving "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)." or other error? if other then plz post error message...

Comment: No. I've disabled request validation. No error, no exception. The browser just says `Bad Request - Invalid URL` and `HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the JSON.stringify(bpics) results a string like this

[{PersonnelName: 'value',$FatherName: 'value',BirthDate: 'value',...},{PersonnelName: 'value',$FatherName: 'value',BirthDate: 'value',...},....]

so the actual url format will be like this
       `window.open("../RawPrint/GetBurseLetterReport/[{PersonnelName: 'value',$FatherName: 'value',BirthDate: 'value',...},{PersonnelName: 'value',$FatherName: 'value',BirthDate: 'value',...},....]/destmanname/university/coursetitle")`

in url you are having special charector ':' which leads to invalid url(400 bad request) error

you should pass the array value at the end as parameter like
`http://yoururl?bpics=JSON.stringify(bpics);`
you can pass any text in parameters so you wont get 400 error even if you pass special charectors in parameters.

and inside controller write something like this

`public ActionResult GetBurseLetterReport(YourClass[] bpics)
{
....
}`

YourClass contains all properties like PersonalName, FatherName .. 
`public class YourClass
{
public string PersonalName{get;set;}
....
....
}`